# Android WebViewClient callbacks called too often

Tags: android, webview, webviewclient

When I call `WebView#loadUrl` I expect that I should only get a single `WebViewClient#onPageFinished` call and no `WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading` call.  However, I get a `WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading` (which I implement by always calling WebView#loadUrl and returning true) and then two `WebViewClient#onPageFinished` calls with the same URL.

The page I'm loading uses a lot of ajax requests.  Do ajax requests invoke the `WebViewClient`?  My page does not have any meta-refreshes in it.

This is quite frustrating.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a cross-post from [a google groups discussion I started on the topic](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-developers/sG964GdoeHg/discussion).

I've done more research, and I think I understand everything that's going on.

Here is my `WebViewClient`:

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
  @Override
  public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    System.out.println("onPageStarted: " + url);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
    System.out.println("shouldOverrideUrlLoading: " + url);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String url) {
    System.out.println("onPageFinished: " + url);
  }
}
```

I have the following URL redirects from my server:

```
http://example.com/resource -> http://example.com/user-name/resource
http://example.com/logout.jsp -> http://example.com/login/logout
http://example.com/login/logout -> http://example.com/login
```

These URLs are part of a server that I don't control, so I just have to deal with the behavior.

Here is the output from loading `http://example.com/resource`

```
onPageStarted: http://example.com/resource
onPageStarted: http://example.com/user-name/resource
shouldOverrideUrlLoading: http://example.com/user-name/resource
onPageFinished: hhttp://example.com/user-name/resource
```

at this point, my `WebView` has blank content.  I must wait until after the second `onPageFinished` to grab my content.

```
onPageStarted: http://example.coms/user-name/resource
onPageFinished: http://example.com/user-name/resource
```

Here is the output from loading `http://example.com/logout.jsp`

```
onPageStarted: http://example.com/logout.jsp
onPageStarted: http://example.com/login/logout
shouldOverrideUrlLoading: http://example.com/login/logout
onPageFinished: http://example.com/login/logout
onPageStarted: http://example.com/login/logout
onPageStarted: http://example.com/login
shouldOverrideUrlLoading: http://example.com/login
onPageFinished: http://example.com/login
```

again, at this point, my `WebView` has a blank page. I have to wait until the 3rd `onPageFinished` to get my content from the `WebView`.

```
onPageStarted: http://example.com/login
onPageFinished: http://example.com/login
```

Based on the documentation, I don't expect this behavior.  Notice that there is an unbalanced number of `onPageStarted`s and `onPageFinished`s.  I especially dislike how `onPageFinished` gets called with my redirected URL, yet the `WebView` doesn't contain my content.  I understand that this behavior is probably unchangeable, but this unexpected behavior should at least be documented.

Comment: @heath_borders do you know what's exactly happening inside the webview, I'm looking into it, since I'm having problems due to multiple calls to onPageFinished.

Answer (score 4):

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
    System.out.println("shouldOverrideUrlLoading: " + url);
    return true;
}
```

You don't need to explicitly call *webView.loadUrl(url)*. By overriding to return true will automatically get your existing webview to handle the new page load. By unnecessarily invoking that, it starts a brand new cycle of webpage load on that webView in the middle of the original cycles (onPageStarted -> onPageFinished) hence extra cycle of callback triggered in total.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't even have access to the server anymore, so I can't test it under the same conditions. Also, I'm sure `WebView`'s behavior has changed in the years since I posted. It'll probably be a while beofr I can verify that this is correct.